# Does the diagnostic odds ratio for a test increase, decrease or not change if there is a change in the prevalence of a disease?

Tags: probability, statistics, ratio

Does the diagnostic odds ratio of a test change if there is an outbreak of the particular disease in the population? If so, does it increase, decrease or just stay the same?

Answer (score 0):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagnostic_odds_ratio):

> The *diagnostic odds ratio* is defined mathematically as $$\text{Diagnostic odds ratio, DOR} = \dfrac{TP/FP}{FN/TN}$$
>   where $TP,FN,FP,TN$ are the number of true positives, false negatives, false positives and true negatives respectively.
>
> ...
>
> The diagnostic odds ratio may be expressed in terms of the *sensitivity* and *specificity* of the test: $$\text{DOR} = \frac{\text{sensitivity}\times\text{specificity}}{\left(1-\text{sensitivity}\right)\times\left(1-\text{specificity}\right)}$$

So if the sensitivity and specificity stay the same then the diagnostic odds ratio should also stay the same